# Получить id роли активного сеанса в postgres

Tags: postgresql9.6

Как мне получить id Роли активного подключения не весь список, через pg_roles ? Есть ли какая нибудь системная переменная, возможно функция
как на примере `SELECT user`.

Comment: К примеру `select current_role;` Есть [похожий ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22502312/6752984) . Там хорошо описаны различия `current_user, session_user`. Лучше опишите задачу, которую решаете и какой результат хотите получить.